# Set default values for webcontrols in base class

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have a few web forms that proccess excel files, so in order to make this easier, I have a base class like this:

```
public abstract class ExcelImporter : Page {
    public abstract RadAsyncUpload FileUpload { get; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            DefineRadAyncUpload();
        }
    }

    private void DefinirRadAyncUpload()
    {
        FileUpload.Skin = Skin;
        FileUpload.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        FileUpload.TemporaryFolder = "~/temp";
        FileUpload.OnClientFileUploaded = "PostBackAsyncUploadComplete";
        FileUpload.AllowedFileExtensions = new[] { "xls", "xlsx" };
        FileUpload.MaxFileInputsCount = 1;
        FileUpload.FileUploaded += FileUploadOnFileUploaded;
    }

    protected abstract void FileUploadOnFileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs fileUploadedEventArgs);
}
```

Everything i'm setting in the Define method is working, except the extension filter.
What am I doing wrong? is there another moment that I shoud set this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Give this a shot:

```
FileUpload.FileFilters.Add(new FileFilter("Microsoft Excel (*.xls;*.xlsx)", new [] { "xls", "xlsx" }));
```

From [The Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-file-filtering.html):

"Forth from Q1 2011 RadAsyncUpload supports file filtering. A file filter is an object with two properties -- Description and Extensions. The extensions property accepts a comma separated list of extensions, upon which the select file dialog should be filtered. The description property, as its name suggest, describes the extensions set."

Also:

"Please have in mind that when RadAsyncUpload is utilizing its IFrame module (when neither Flash nor Silverlight is installed) no filtering capabilities are available. This is because browsers don’t provide native file filtering support at all.
One can apply as many filters as they want. Then, the user can choose among different filters via the Files of type combo box."

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's not possible to filter the list of choices: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/how-to-filter-out-unwanted-file-types-radupload.aspx.  The AllowedFileExtensions is just a validation property - so if you tried to upload anything other than those, it will throw an error.  I assume you were trying to filter the list of choices?

Comment: Yes, but it's funny, it worked before(when we had to put it in the aspx, now, not even there)

Comment: Alas, I must have been looking at some old forums.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Man! still nothing.
I think, maybe i'm doing this at the wrong place. I'll try some more on monday, thanks =)

Comment: I think it's time we both call it a day :)

Comment: Haha, so.. i've been reading, and apparently, this can't be done. It only works if you use silverlight or flash components.